# job scheduler android nougat every one minute not working

Tags: android

Am using job scheduler
 `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                      jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
                            .setMinimumLatency(60000)
                            .setRequiredNetworkType(networkType)
                            .setPersisted(isPersistent)
                            .build();
                } else {
                      jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
                            .setPeriodic(60000)
                            .setRequiredNetworkType(networkType)
                            .setPersisted(isPersistent)
                            .build();
                }`
setMinimumLatency(60000)-->  its  not execute every one minute .

Answer (score 0):

`setMinimumLatency()` does not set up a recurring job. It sets up a job that will occur once.

Comment: Then how can i execute process in every one minute in nougat version

Comment: @RajeshKanna: In general, you can't. `AlarmManager` will let you schedule recurring work every minute, though you have to do so manually (e.g., `setExact()` to trigger the work, where part of the work is calling `setExact()` to trigger the next pulse of work). However, most Android 6.0+ devices are in Doze mode most of the time, and during that time, your alarms will not be invoked. Users have stated fairly loudly that they do not like apps that try to do frequent background work like this, and so Google has tightened up Android to match.